# BigInteger/SecureRandom in jar very slow when called from Coldfusion

Tags: java, performance, coldfusion, jar, biginteger

I have a class that creates a random string based on BigInteger. All works fine and efficient when run standalone (Windows, 22ms).

```
private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

public String testMe() {
     return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(30)
}
```

When this code is put into a library (jar) and called from Coldfusion (9.0.2), this code hangs for 1 to 1.5 minutes (on my server, linux). This code is called from a cfc:

```
<cfset myTest = CreateObject("java", "com.acme.MyTest")>

<cffunction name="runTest" access="public">
    <cfset var value = myTest.testMe()/>
</cffunction>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure `BigInteger` is the cause and not `SecureRandom`?

Comment: @Jason C: Not sure but problem is the same. When run in my IDE, this code takes around 22 milliseconds. I wonder what is going on within Coldfusion and why.

Comment: Most likely it is taking a long time to generate and compile your code.  How long does it take after the 10th time or 10,000th time (when the code has warmed up)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: It doesn't make a difference. I actually put some logging around the call and it is really hanging in there. I will run the code on the server later from the console without coldfusion to check if the system has a funny java or something.

Comment: I just run this test class on the server but without Coldfusion. It takes on avg. 2 to 4 milliseconds. Something with coldfusion seems to be wrong here.

Comment: The server has Java 1.7.0_21 installed but Coldfusion is using its own which is 1.6.0_29.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am just astonished that the difference was not noticable on my Windows box.

There are different SecureRandom strategies.  On window it could be using a random seed based on the host name, which for windows can wander off to a DNS to get a reverse lookup the first time.  This can time out the request after a minute or so.

I would ensure you have a recent update of Java because I believe this is a problem which was fixed in some update of Java 6. (Not to do with SecureRandom, but with first network operation being incredibly slow)

BTW This was tested on a Windows 7 box and the first time, it hung for a few seconds, but not after that.

---

If your code is hanging to 60 to 90 seconds, it is not due to this method, far more likely you are performing a GC, and this method is stopping because it allocated memory.

---

While BigInteger is slow, SecureRandom is much, much slower.  If you want this to be faster, use plain Random.

It would be slightly faster if you used less bits.

BTW I would use base 36 (the maximum), rather than base 30.

```
static volatile String dontOptimiseAway = null;
public static void testRandomBigInteger(Random random) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    int runs = 10000;
    for(int i=0;i< runs;i++) {
        dontOptimiseAway = new BigInteger(130, random).toString(36);
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("%s took %.1f micro-seconds on average%n", random.getClass().getSimpleName(), time/runs/1e3);
}
public static void main(String... ignored) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        testRandomBigInteger(new Random());
        testRandomBigInteger(new SecureRandom());
    }
}
```

prints

```
Random took 1.7 micro-seconds on average
SecureRandom took 2.1 micro-seconds on average
```

The time to generate the string is significant, but still no where near enough to cause a multi-second delay.

Comment: Thanks, Random seems to fix it. However I am just astonished that the difference was not noticable on my Windows box. I don't think it's the GC, it's reproducable everytime.

Comment: I know made Coldfusion use Java 1.7.0_21 and it works like a charm. (Not sure though if everything else just works as well)

Comment: So I suspect it was a bug relating to the version of Java. I would try 7 update 25 if you can.